# confusion about synchronization of SQLAlchemy objects with database

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm going through the SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) and I'm finding it super difficult to understand when/why a Python object will reflect the latest data in the database.

Here is a sequence of events that confuses me:

- First we create a user `ed_user` and add it to the session. Its `id` is `None` because the row hasn't been written to the database.
- Then we create a different user `our_user` which is obtained by querying the database with a query that will match `ed_user`. So `our_user` and `ed_user` are actually the same user. When we query either `our_user.id` or `ed_user.id` after this query has taken place, we see that the `id` has now been assigned because `ed_user` was flushed to the database when the SELECT query was written.
- Then we edit `ed_user` and add some other unrelated rows, and issue a session commit.
- Finally we then read the value of `ed_user.id` again and it causes the database to issue a SELECT query to get the latest value of id since the previous commit ended the previous transaction.

I find this extremely confusing because in the first step, before `ed_user` was ever written to the database, SQLAlchemy was content to give us a `None` value for `id` **even though it could have obtained an id if it went ahead and flushed the write to the database** but for some reason once the row was written to the database once, SQLAlchemy thinks it is important to keep it up-to-date (in the last step) by refreshing the data when it is read. Why is this happening and what controls this behavior?

Bottom line, I have no idea what logic I can rely on regarding when/why/how my Python objects will be kept up-to-date with the database, and any extra clarity you can offer will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and shed some light on the [state management](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html) in SQLAlchemy by going through your bullet points.

> - First we create a user `ed_user` and add it to the session. Its `id` is `None` because the row hasn't been written to the database.

Before adding the newly created Ed-object to the session it is in **transient** state; it has not been added to a session and it does not have a database identity. When you add it to a session it moves to **pending** state. It has not been [flushed](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#flushing) to the database, but will be when the next flush occurs. If you have [autoflush](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.autoflush) enabled (the default), all pending changes will be flushed before issuing the next query operation in order to make sure that the states of the session and the database are in sync when querying, which brings us to:

> - Then we create a different user `our_user` which is obtained by querying the database with a query that will match `ed_user`. So `our_user` and `ed_user` are actually the same user.

It is a bit misleading to say that you create `our_user`. Instead you perform the query and bind the result to the name `our_user`:

> ```
> >>> our_user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first()
> ```

Here it is important to remember that all pending changes are flushed *before* this query takes place. That means that the changes held in the object bound to the name `ed_user` are sent to the database and SQLAlchemy fetches its database identity (`id` is not `None` anymore), moving it to **persistent** state and adding it to the [identity map](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html).

Since all that took place *before* the query, you get the row that was created when the Ed-object was flushed as the result, and inspecting that row's identity (using the identity map) SQLAlchemy notices that it in fact represents the existing object held in the session, the one bound to the name `ed_user` before. That is why both `ed_user.id` and `our_user.id` give you the same value – in fact `ed_user is our_user` will also be `True`; they are the same object.

> - Finally we then read the value of `ed_user.id` again and it causes the database to issue a `SELECT` query to get the latest value of `id` since the previous commit ended the previous transaction.

By default SQLAlchemy expires all database loaded state after a [commit](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#committing), in order to keep you from working on stale data. Some other thread or process might already have committed its changes in between. Like most things this behaviour can be controlled by passing [`expire_on_commit=False`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.expire_on_commit) to [`sessionmaker`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker) or a [`Session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) directly, if you really need to.